# ListView Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, xaml, listview

I Have three objects in a combo box when they are selected the items are listed in the List View. The items are added but there is no text inside the rows like the names of the objects. and when I remove the ListView.View from my Xaml the items displays "(Collection)"

```
//ComboBox Binding
    public void BindComboBox()
        {
            using (DataClassesDataContext DC = new DataClassesDataContext())
            {                
                cbItem.Items.Clear();
                foreach (tblProduct R in DC.tblProducts)
                    cbItem.Items.Add(R);
                cbItem.DisplayMemberPath = "ProductName";
            }

//Combobox selectionChanged
            List<PIDData> items = new List<PIDData> { };

            IEnumerable<PIDData> query = items.Where(item => item.PName != null);
            lvDataBinding.Items.Add(items);

            txt1.Text = query.ToString();

//Xaml
 <ListView Margin="338,20,1,16" Name="lvDataBinding">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PName}">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="Product Name" Width="100">Product Name</GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn>                   
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbItem" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,315,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="321" SelectionChanged="cbItem_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Comment: `lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = items;` assuming `items` has been populated properly...

Comment: @har07 I have used the itemSource before but then no items are added to the listview at all. This is my PIDData:

Comment: public struct PIDData
        {
            public long PIdentity { get; set; }
            public string PName { get; set; }
            public string PPrice { get; set; }
            public string PSerial { get; set; }
            public string PDescription { get; set; }
            public string PType { get; set; }
            public string PPosition { get; set; }
            public Binary PImage { get; set; }
        }

Answer (score 1):

Well what you are doing is that you are adding the LINQ Query result as "one object" to your list view. So the list view is not dealing with each piddata but with one "IEnumable".

So either you are adding them one by one or you change to assignment of ItemsSource.

Comment: yes I only want to show the Product name in the list view but why doesn't it show the string value of the items?